# Calculating dates in sharepoint list

Tags: list, date-time

I have two columns in a list, one called 'start date' and one called 'renewal date' what I need is for the renewal date to default to a year after the start date, i.e. Start date = 07/09/2013 and for the renewal date to be 06/09/2014, if that makes sense?

The above dates are in the format dd/mm/yyyy. For clarity, please could you answer with dates in the same format.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a calculated column, formatted as Date and Time, with a formula like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Start Date])+1,MONTH([Start Date]),DAY([Start Date]))
```

Comment: +1 But very occasionally you might get an error on leap years (e.g. 29/2/12 -> 29/2/13, which doesn't exist).

Comment: As long as you're formatting the field as Date and Time, it will work out the leap year for you. So in your example, it would return 01/03/13

Comment: I just tested this and can confirm you're correct. Very interesting.